# Double Include Prevention Code in PHP Prevents Doxygen From Generating Documentation

Tags: php, doxygen

I am writing relatively complex PHP applications and have several files for class definitions formatted as follows:

```
<?php

if(!class_exists("FooBar"))
{

/**
 * This is documentation for the class FooBar
 */
class FooBar
{
    /**
     * Documentation for FooBar's constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        ;
    }
}

} // class_exists
```

This is to prevent multiple definition errors with complex class hierarchies and applications.

However, Doxygen does not document any classes that are specified this way. Commenting out or removing the `if(!class_exists())` statement causes Doxygen to correctly document this class, but introduces errors with applications.

Is there any way I can force Doxygen to generate documentation for these classes?

Comment: This is not an answer, this might be subject to discussion, and ofcourse I do not know how your class hierarchies are build up, but it seems to me that using namespaces is would be a better approach to prevent multiple definition errors...

Comment: Well, defining classes conditionally (inside `if` blocks) is a really, *really* bad idea. If you have a large/complex code base then you should be using [namespaces](http://php.net/namespace) to organize your code. In other words, you should not be trying to somehow force Doxygen to handle bad practices; you should not be using bad practices to begin with.

Comment: Namespaces do not solve double includes for even very simple class hierarchies, otherwise I would have used them. If I have base class A, and sub-classes B and C, then use both B and C in my application, the effect is an include statement for class A is being called twice resulting in a double definition error.

Comment: @MarcusHarrison Well, if you define a class in a file then it should never be included more than once, anyway. Hiding poorly written code does not make it okay.

Comment: I don't understand your response.

Classes A, B and C are each written in separate files. Class B and C both inherit from class A, so they must both have `include("classa.php")` in their files. If a developer uses either B or C, but not both, `include("classa.php")` is only being called once and the program runs. If a developer wants to use both B and C in the same application, they must call `include("classb.php")` and `include("classc.php")`. This means `include("classa.php")` is called twice, resulting in two definitions of class A. I don't understand how namespaces prevent this issue.

Comment: @MarcusHarrison Ah. Autoloading would fix this problem. [This article](http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) explains it quite nicely.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This adequately solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Sverri in the comments, I also think that autoloading is a good way to solve your problem (what it already did, as it seems).

But just for the case you (or someone else) is looking for a doxygen-only solution:

You can use [INPUT_FILTERS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) in doxygen to remove or change some parts of the source code before creating the documentation.

You can use the following php code to remove all lines containing `if(!class_exists` and the braces `{` `}` that belong to this `if`-block, as long as it is not followed by another block.

```
// input
$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

// removes the whole line
list($head,$tail) = preg_split('/.*if\(!class_exists\(.+/', $source, 2);   

$openingBracePos = strpos($tail,'{');
$closingBracePos = strrpos($tail,'}');

if($openingBracePos !== false && $closingBracePos !== false)
    $source = $head . substr($tail,$openingBracePos+1,
                             $closingBracePos-$openingBracePos-1);

echo $source;
```

This filter truns

```
<?php

if(!class_exists("FooBar"))     // This comment will also disappear
{

/**
 * This is documentation for the class FooBar
 */
class FooBar
{
    /**
     * Documentation for FooBar\'s constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        ;
    }
}

} // class_exists
```

into

```
<?php



/**
 * This is documentation for the class FooBar
 */
class FooBar
{
    /**
     * Documentation for FooBar's constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        ;
    }
}
```

*Note*: On windows I have to call the filter like this: `C:\xampp\php\php.exe php_var_filter.php`

You can find some more input filters to improve doxygen's php support on [GitHub](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters).