# Doxygen not documenting php code inside if tags

Tags: php, class, documentation, doxygen

I am using doxygen, but it doesn't document some of my classes. All these classes are called in the following way:

```
<?php
if(!class_exists('a')){
    class a{

        function b(){
            print 'c';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I assume it has to do with if(!class_exists('a')), how can i let doxygen still document this?

Comment: Have you tried putting a docblock above the class?  Along with you, I'm guess that it has to do with the class being inside a control structure.

Comment: Yes i did, but i also setup doxygen to document undocumented structures.

Comment: Okay, I was curious.  I use doxygen also, just not in the way you show above.  I was thinking a docblock above the class would've forced it to document that structure.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24485609/3440545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen has many issues documenting php code. And many of them can be corrected by using an `input_filter`.

Use the following code as filter

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$regexp = '#(<\?php[\s]+)(if\(!class_exists\([^\)]+\)\)\{)([\s\S]*)(\})([\s]*\?>)#';
$replace = '$1 $3 $5';
$source = preg_replace($regexp, $replace, $source);
echo $source;
?>
```

and enter it as

```
/path/to/php php_var_filter.php
```

into the `INPUT_FILTER` setting.

Notice: This way you can fix many doxygen issues. If something does not work, it is beacause of a difference between c (or c++) code to php code (most likly). You can use the input_filter to change your php code to look more like c code. This will fix many problems.

**Edit**
Maybe you also want to think about an autoload function. I think this is a better way to get the `if(!class_exists(..))`-result.

**Edit**
I just noticed I already answerd a similar question different. You can also use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655189/3440545).

You can find some more input filters to improve doxygen's php support on [GitHub](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters).