# Doxygen - PHP traits

Tags: php, doxygen, traits

We have grown fond of Doxygen, it certainly appears to create the best looking documentation.

However, we use PHP and Traits are simply ignored / absent from generated documentation.

Are we missing a trick here,  or are Traits simply not compatible?

Comment: Maybe you can write a filter to make php traits look like c++ traits (if supported). have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26206860/3440545) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25655189/3440545) answer of mine for an example of filters.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Hello, I looked into your contribution on git, which is great. Unfortunately I have not enough knowledge in C++ to understand how to convert a PHP trait syntax into a C++ trait syntax. After a short glimps at it, do you think replacing `trait traitName { [methods] }` by `template traitName { [methods] }` could do it ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I also don't know much about C++. But you can just try it. The worst that could happen is, that it does not work. Then you can remove the filter :) But I can take a closer look at it. If I find a solution, I post it here and in my GitHub repo.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen What I tried didn't work. But while reading some introduction on C++ traits, I'm no longer sure that c++ traits are a similar feature as php traits.

Comment: @Gavin Were you able to have Doxygen generate documentation of traits ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer See my answer. Maybe this works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traits are just not supported by doxygen.

Since PHP does not support inheritance from multiple classes, traits are the way to extend a class by functions of multiple "classes".

C++ does support inheritance from multiple classes, so try this filter:

```
// make traits to classes
$regexp = '#trait([\s]+[\S]+[\s]*){#';
$replace = 'class$1{';
$source = preg_replace($regexp, $replace, $source);

// use traits by extending them (classes that not extending a class)
$regexp = '#class([\s]+[\S]+[\s]*)(implements[\s]+[\S]+[\s]*)?{[\s]+use([^;]+);#';
$replace = 'class$1 extends $3 $2 {';
$source = preg_replace($regexp, $replace, $source);

// use traits by extending them (classes that already extending a class)
$regexp = '#class([\s]+[\S]+[\s]+extends[\s]+[\S]+[\s]*)(implements[\s]+[\S]+[\s]*){[\s]+use([^;]+);#';
$replace = 'class$1, $3 $2{';
$source = preg_replace($regexp, $replace, $source);
```

This filter does:

1. Transforms traits to classes

   ```
   trait MyTrait{ ... }
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   class MyTrait{ ... }
   ```
2. Transform "using" traits into "extending" traits

   ```
   class MyClass{
       use MyTrait1, MyTrait2;
       ...
   }
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   class MyClass extends MyTrait, MyTrait2{
       ...
   }
   ```

Doxygen documents this as a multiple inheritance. Maybe this works for you.

You can find this and some more [doxygen filters for PHP in my repository on GitHub](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters).

Comment: This really looks promising. Thanks for that excellent work. I will try it today.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot accept it as an answer... I edit it for the case when a class `extends` and `implements`.

Comment: With this little addition, everything works great. I cannot accept your answer because I did not ask the question.

Comment: I just saw this. sorry I'm not awake yet :D

Comment: I had not yet turned my attention to fixing this.  Project deadlines became more important than the documentation.  This works great for me.  Many thanks.